# Website lagging on scroll when adding images to a react app

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, performance, smooth-scrolling

I have built a portfolio website with react here https://andrewkaras.me, but on selected work section you will notice lags when scrolling through project images (especially on Safari). 
Here is the code for the projects container and for individual projects:
Myprojects:

```
import React from 'react'

import colors from '../../assets/colors.png'
import colorsWebp from '../../assets/colors.webp'
import crwn from '../../assets/crwn.png'
import crwnWebp from '../../assets/crwn.webp'
import devchat from '../../assets/devchat.png'
import devchatWebp from '../../assets/devchat.webp'
import movies from '../../assets/movies.png'
import moviesWebp from '../../assets/movies.webp'
import Project from '../../Components/Project/Project'
import styles from './MyProjects.module.scss'

const MyProjects = () => {
  return (
    <div className={styles.container} id="myProjects">
      <div className={styles.myProjects}>
        <div className={styles.headerWrapper}>
          <h2 className={styles.header}>Selected Work</h2>
        </div>
        <Project
          name="CRWN Clothing"
          image={crwn}
          imageWebp={crwnWebp}
          color="rgb(157, 169, 238)"
          hoverColor="rgb(177, 189, 258)"
          link="crwnclothing.andrewkaras.me"
          githubLink="https://github.com/Justbigmack/CRWN-Clothing"
          text="An e-commerce web-app that allows you to easily purchase clothes. Payments are processed via Stripe API. It is built with React, Redux, Redux-Sagas and Firebase"
        />
        <Project
          right
          name="React Colors"
          image={colors}
          imageWebp={colorsWebp}
          project="colors"
          color="rgb(161, 106, 195)"
          hoverColor="rgb(181, 126, 215)"
          link="colors.andrewkaras.me"
          githubLink="https://github.com/Justbigmack/react-colors"
          text="React Colors is an app allowing you to generate color palettes for your projects by leveraging easy to use UI and drag and drop system. The project is put together using React, CSS in JS, Material UI and features some React Router animations"
        />
        <Project
          name="DevChat"
          image={devchat}
          imageWebp={devchatWebp}
          project="devchat"
          color="rgb(251, 93, 81)"
          hoverColor="rgb(271, 113, 101)"
          link="devchat.andrewkaras.me"
          githubLink="https://github.com/Justbigmack/dev-chat"
          text="DevChat is a simplified clone of a well-known app - Slack. Devchat allows desktop and large tablet users to exchange messages, files and much more. The project is developed using React, Redux, Firebase and Semantic UI"
        />
        <Project
          right
          name="React Movies"
          image={movies}
          imageWebp={moviesWebp}
          project="movies"
          color="rgb(134, 191, 211)"
          hoverColor="rgb(154, 211, 231)"
          link="movies.andrewkaras.me"
          githubLink="https://github.com/Justbigmack/react-movies"
          text="React Movies is a web-application that allows you to search for your favorite movies. It utilizes React Router and pulls information from TMDB via API"
        />
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default React.memo(MyProjects)
```

One project:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'

import { ReactComponent as GithubIcon } from '../../assets/github.svg'
import styles from './Project.module.scss'

const Project = ({
  name,
  color,
  hoverColor,
  image,
  imageWebp,
  githubLink,
  link,
  right,
  text
}) => {
  const [hover, setHover] = useState(false)
  const [hoverGH, setHoverGH] = useState(false)
  return (
    <div
      className={right ? styles.projectContainerRight : styles.projectContainer}
    >
      <div className={styles.imageContainer} style={{ backgroundColor: color }}>
        <picture>
          <source type="image/webp" srcSet={imageWebp} />
          <source type="image/png" srcSet={image} />
          <img src={image} alt="Project of mine" />
        </picture>
      </div>
      <div className={styles.projectTech}>Web-App</div>
      <div className={styles.projectInfo}>
        <h3 className={styles.projectName}>
          {name}
          <div className={styles.projectGithub}>
            <a href={githubLink}>
              <GithubIcon
                onMouseEnter={() => {
                  setHoverGH(true)
                }}
                onMouseLeave={() => {
                  setHoverGH(false)
                }}
                className={styles.githubIcon}
                style={
                  hoverGH
                    ? {
                        fill: color
                      }
                    : {
                        fill: hoverColor
                      }
                }
              />
            </a>
          </div>
        </h3>
        <h4 className={styles.projectText}>{text}</h4>

        <a
          className={styles.projectLink}
          onMouseEnter={() => {
            setHover(true)
          }}
          onMouseLeave={() => {
            setHover(false)
          }}
          style={
            hover
              ? {
                  color: color
                }
              : {
                  color: hoverColor
                }
          }
          href={`https://${link}`}
        >
          {link}
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default React.memo(Project)
```

Everything is okay, if I add the same image to all projects, but as soon as I pass each project an individual image, it starts lagging on scroll. I am having trouble trying to figure out why.

Comment: Can't reproduce, everything is smooth even with cache disabled

Comment: hey @ZohirSalak. I am running into issues on MacOS (mostly, Safari). Which OS and browser are you using?

Comment: Ah yes i forgot to mention. Windows, chrome 78 and FF 70

Comment: got it! good to know, thanks for testing @ZohirSalak. I fixed it just now by adding -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0); to the app. I read about this and found that safari is trying to be quite power efficient, so it can cause scroll issues. That trick makes it run smoothly.

Comment: May be images are high reso.